# SwiftUI ignoresSafeArea for one child view only doesn't work as expected

Tags: swiftui

I want to create view in SwiftUI with TextFiled on top and some Buttons underneath and during TextField editing, keyboard should cover Buttons but lift TextField.

I tried applying .ignoresSafeArea() for VStack with Buttons but it doesn't work as expected. Keyboard still lift whole view causing TextFild to escape the screen on top.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "Text"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("TEXT", text: $text)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(height: 450)
                .background(Color.blue)
            
            VStack {
                Button("Button 1", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
                Button("Button 2", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
                Button("Button 3", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
                Button("Button 4", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
                Button("Button 5", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .border(Color.green, width: 10)
    }
}
```

**without keyboard:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8kdE.png)

**with keyboard:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw7Do.png)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you could try the .layoutpriority tag. Make the buttons a higher priority than the text perhaps? You could also rework the buttons so that they take up less room. One other thing, you could also change the type of keyboard presented, unsure if it will take up less space.

Comment: @user3069232 I've tried layout Priority but it did nothing to the view layout

Comment: Don't give anything fixed frames... just let SwiftUI come up with some defaults

Answer (score 1):

Use below `ViewModifier` to achive actual result.

```
extension View { //Add this View extension 
    @ViewBuilder
    func wrappedInScrollView(when condition: Bool) -> some View {
        if condition {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false, content: {
                self
            })
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Make Below `ViewModifier`.

```
struct OverflowContentViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var contentOverflow: Bool = false

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { contentGeometry in
                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                        contentOverflow = contentGeometry.size.height > geometry.size.height
                    }
                }
            )
            .wrappedInScrollView(when: contentOverflow)
        }
    }
 }
```

Use Like This add `ViewModifier` to your `VStack`

```
VStack {
        
        TextField("TEXT", text: $text)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .frame(height: 450)
            .background(Color.blue)
        
        VStack {
            Button("Button 1", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
            Button("Button 2", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
            Button("Button 3", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
            Button("Button 4", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
            Button("Button 5", action: {}).frame(height: 50)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    .border(Color.green, width: 10)
    .modifier(OverflowContentViewModifier()) //Add Modifier here...
```